# Adding a pattern in grok file in Logstash Grok File - Creating Grok Pattern

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

Here is my log pattern for which I am trying to write Grok for (Parsing logs)

Log Pattern : 
2016-12-05 17:31:10:675 WARNI Received signal: SIGTERM [OSignalHandler]

Another log pattern : 
2016-12-05 16:52:12:805 SEVER Unable to listen for connections using configured hosts [OServerNetworkListener]

I see the grok file in logstash folder in 
**C:\logstash-5.0.0\logstash-5.0.0\vendor\bundle\jruby\1.9\gems\logstash-patterns-core-4.0.2\patterns..**

In grok-patterns file - there is log-level:

```
LOGLEVEL ([Aa]lert|ALERT|[Tt]race|TRACE|[Dd]ebug|DEBUG|[Nn]otice|NOTICE|[Ii]nfo|INFO|[Ww]arn?(?:ing)?|WARN?(?:ING)?|[Ee]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[Cc]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[Ff]atal|FATAL|[Ss]evere|SEVERE|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?)
```

I want to add WARNI and SEVER present in my log to this Pattern so that I can parse the log.

Tried adding WARNI and SEVER in the pattern mentioned below :

```
LOGLEVEL1 ([Aa]lert|ALERT|[Tt]race|TRACE|[Dd]ebug|DEBUG|[Nn]otice|NOTICE|[Ii]nfo|INFO|[Ww]arni?(?:ng)?|WARNI?(?:NG)?|[Ee]rr?(?:or)?|ERR?(?:OR)?|[Cc]rit?(?:ical)?|CRIT?(?:ICAL)?|[Ff]atal|FATAL|[Ss]ever|SEVER|EMERG(?:ENCY)?|[Ee]merg(?:ency)?)
```

But getting grokparsefailure. Can anyone help on writing a grok pattern in the grok-patterns file?

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks !

Comment: Read the doc on [custom patterns](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html#_custom_patterns). To use custom patterns, you have to create a file and add them there.

Comment: thanks baudsp. it helped me in creating the grok using patterns file.